# How to detach element from std:queue

Tags: c++, stl

I have a global `std::queue` from which multiple threads pick up elements one by one in synchronized manner. The queue is of structures.

Each thread call `.front()` to get the first/next element and makes local copy of it and then `.pop()` it from the queue (so that another thread gets next element by calling `.front()`)

**Problem:** Making copy of elements has performance impact.

Is there any way just to **detach** element from queue? (So that it will not be part of the queue anymore. At the same time it won't be deleted as well. Caller will take care of deletion.)

Comment: You could move from it.

Comment: @chris Make that an answer (sorry, about previous comment, mixed it up with `priority_queue`)

Comment: OOps yes you are correct. I just looked at queue methods and didn't find any. lol. Thanks.

Comment: Yes please make that as answer.

Comment: @Angew, No time; at work :p

Answer (score 5):

The queue operation you request doesn't exist. Alternatives:

- Make the structure movable. Move from the `front()` and then `pop()` the moved-from object. Be aware that if your structure is very large (for example it has a large array as a member), then moving can still be slow because the contents of the object itself must still be copied. However, if the structure is expensive to copy because of `string` members or whatever, then it will be cheaper to move.
- Use a queue of smart pointers to the real data. Copying a smart pointer is pretty cheap, so this might well satisfy your performance requirements even though copying the whole object doesn't.
- Instead of using a queue, use a `list`, and `splice()` the front element into another list used by the consumer thread. Remove it from the per-thread list once it's processed. I don't really recommend this but I mention it because it's the closest thing there is to literally detaching an object from a container. It's detached from the original list but *must* be simultaneously re-attached to a different list.

Comment: **Regd use of smart pointers:** Structure created on stack gets copied straight to queue. Creating its copy on heap would be overhead. **Regd using list** list don't suit to my requirement. I had infact moved to `queue` from `list` **Regd moving** If moving actually copies, then is it not same what currently I am doing?

Comment: @Andrew How is a "copy on the heap" more overhead than "a copy in the queue?" You wouldn't even have to create a copy in the stack in the first place. And about moves, an example: copying a `std::vector` copies the entire contents of the vector. Moving a `std::vector` copies the 3 pointers (or something similar, based on implementation) actually stored inside the `std::vector` object. See the difference?

Comment: @Angew: Sry I never used move before. It's because Steve said **because the contents of the object itself must still be copied.** I got little confused. But I'll explore this option now based on what you said.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::queue` isn't normally a linked list; the elements (or at least blocks of the elements) are contiguous.  If copying is an issue, you could use a queue of pointers; I've had good success in the past using a queue of dynamically allocated pointers, using `std::unique_ptr` (actually `std::auto_ptr`, since it was in the past.)

Comment: I had this arrangement in place (using `new` specifically) but because of memory fragmentation and other issues I plan to let containers to do it for me (as containers allocate in chunks etc). So I just create object on stack and pass it to queue.

Comment: @Andrew If the only reason was memory fragmentation, then a pool allocator for the objects might be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am new to pool allocator. Do you have any link showing examples so that I can pick it up quick. (In short, I am trying to getting rid of `new` from the code, as much as possible.)

Comment: @Andrew You'd still have the `new`, but it would resolve to a class specific `new`, which obtained the memory from a pool of fixed length blocks.  All of the links I could find seemed oriented to an allocator for a standard container, which makes them a lot more complicated than otherwise necessary, but you might be able to gland some information from them.  And boost has a pool allocator as well, although I'm not familiar with it.